# How do I add a formula with VBA that refers to another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I searched but didn't found what I was looking for.
My goal is to have a big number of cells that shows the value of other cells in other sheets like a simple "=january!BP$43".
But I want to add this with a loop, here a simplified example:

```
  For sorte = 0 To 5
    For mois = 0 To 11
        Sheets(2).Range(4+k, 1 + mois + j).Formula = "=Sheets(3 + mois).Cells(40+i, 2 + sorte)"
    Next
    j = j + 13
    i=i+15
    k=k+1
Next
```

I tried it without the " " around "Sheets...)" and it works but just inserts the value and not the formula. 
Any Idea? 
Thanks a lot

PS: j,i,k are just here to show that I have other variables coming there to change the position.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that everything in between quotation marks will be copied as a string. You need to close the quotation marks whenever you want to use the value of the variable, not the variable name:

```
For mois = 0 To 11
    Sheets(2).Range(4+k, 1 + mois + j).Formula = "=Sheets(" & 3 + mois & ").Cells(" & 40+i & "," & 2 + sorte& ")"
Next
```

However, wouldn't it be easier to just use Excel and copy to the cells you need?

Comment: However, wouldn't it be easier to just use Excel and copy to the cells you need?

Nope, I should then do it 1200 times and if one day I one to change or improve something, I should then do it all again. So now I do it by one click and my excel sheets are created and ready to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place the sheet name in using `Sheets(3 + mois).Name`, and it will be easiest to refer to the row and column using R1C1 notation:

```
For sorte = 0 To 5
    For mois = 0 To 11
        Sheets(2).Cells(4+k, 1 + mois + j).FormulaR1C1 = "='" & Sheets(3 + mois).Name & "'!R" & (40+i) & "C" & (2 + sorte)
    Next
    j = j + 13
    i=i+15
    k=k+1
Next
```